# If we don't make a React component as Presentation component, isn't this component not easy to be re-used?

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

I don't quite understand [Dan Abramov's 2019 comment in his article Container vs Presentational component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Is it true that we should still make component Presentational component so that we can re-use them?  If we start making components that have an app state, then this component cannot be re-used easily, because then having two of such component on the same page will let them interfere with each other.

So the component can have state, but only "component state", such as whether the comment box is expanded or not, or even the current text in the comment box, etc. It should not be tightly coupled with a certain state in the app.  Because then we cannot really re-use this component, unless it is for sure a singleton in the whole app, which mean there is no re-use.

So does it really mean we should write our components so that it is re-usable, and let other component pass in the App data as "props"?  This way, we can re-use our components just by passing in different props (and dispatch) from the outer container.

So for our re-usable component, it doesn't matter it is Container or Presentational or combined, just as long as a even higher container can pass it the props and dispatch and let us re-use the component. Is that what Dan really means?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this statement was **more about granularity and separation of biznes logic** ... container usually manages some **app specific** dataset with some set of presentational components.

Of course **container component can be reused**, too. F.e. list of user followers can use common Apollo client (graphql) as long as our backends are composed using the same (shared) schema (by microservices/federation). It can be freely used in different apps and by using render props we can change its look/behaviour.

It's about reusability in general, it's much easier for stateles (presentational) and locally managed state components (class or functional).